# Output only the column under COMMAND of `ps` command in terminal

Tags: command-line, ps

I know that we can easily find the following:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

of all the running processes by using the command:

`sudo ps aux`

My, question is that, is it possible to show the output of only the column under `COMMAND` and nothing else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `-o` flag.

To list only your own processes

```
 ps -o command
```

To list all system processes

```
 ps -e -o command
```

This is not the only way to list commands, they can either be printed with command line flags, or as executable only (which is what `command` option does).

From my comment bellow the answer:

> command, args, and cmd all give full command. In fact man page states
>   command and cmd are aliases for args , with the - flags included. The
>   comm gives the name of the exacutable only. Aliases to that are ucmd
>   and ucomm. I misread about AIX options, those can be actually
>   specified with printf-like format, %a for args, %c for comm

Refer to `man ps` for more info on usage and available format options

Programmatic approach would be a bit redundant , since `ps` already provides us with the formatting options, but it can be done with `awk`, which is much useful when dealing with columnized output.

```
ps aux | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ( i >= 11 ) printf $i" "}; printf "\n" }'
```

Note however, that this code breaks if username contains whitespace, e.g. `john doe`. This can be amended with adding `gsub` function that will elimiate your username from the `ps` list. However, if there is multiple users logged into system, that may be difficult to errase all of the usernames from the output. Thus, you can see that `-o` flag is much more preferred.

Side note, `sudo` is not necessary to for listing all processes with `ps`

Comment: Thank You! Are there any differences between `ps -eo command` & `ps -eo comm`? The only difference I found was in `command` the output was as such: `[kthreadd]` whereas in `comm` the output was as this: `kthreadd`. Does this signify anything?

Comment: @Raphael according to the man page, the difference is that `comm` is AIX format, where as `command` is standard GNU style format. AIX is another *NIX like system, so that option may be used for compatability. Otherwise, no difference

Comment: @Serg, I just executed the `diff <(ps -eo comm) <(ps -eo command)` and there seems to be quite a rattle down there, can you clarify?

Comment: Watch out, the `awk` solution breaks if an username contains spaces ([here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/699439/output-only-the-column-under-command-of-ps-command-in-terminal/699447?noredirect=1#comment1024950_699447)); also maybe just `ps aux | awk '{ for(i=11;i<=NF;i++) {printf $i" "}; printf "\n" }'`?

Comment: @kos yeah, I should have started loop at 11th field anyway,no need for if statement.  I will add that note to my answer.  Perhaps gsub would help us eliminate the username ?

Comment: Yes I think so. That way at least it should be always the 10th field.

Comment: @Andrew So, I've read the manual a little more. So `command`, `args`, and `cmd` all give full command. In fact man page states `command` and `cmd` are aliases for `args` , with the `-` flags included. The `comm` gives the name of the exacutable only. Aliases to that are `ucmd` and `ucomm`.  I misread about AIX options, those can be actually specified with printf-like format, %a for args, %c for comm

Comment: Added the comment and some edits to my answer

Comment: @Serg, your answer sounded greek and latin and I did some homework on the ps' man page and I never thought `ps` could do so much on its own. I agree with `ps -o` suiting all situtations.

Comment: @Andrew sorry, that's a pitfall of using technical vocab too much. Basically, `command` = `args`  = `cmd`, and they all show full command. Example, it would show `myScript.sh -flag 1 -flag 2`. Whereas, `comm` only shows `myScript.sh`

Comment: Yeah, I just looked them up at the bottom of the man page. It says `arg` contains the _command_ with all arguments while `comm` displays the _command alone_ as you had illustrated in your examples, thanks! Wondering why `args` has so many aliases...

Comment: @Andrew most likely due to the fact that `ps` command differed from system to system: there's BSD options in there, AIX, probably others. It's not only `ps` thing , many other programs have extra options for compatibility

Comment: I have a book on System V Unix , which was used in like 80s and its implementation of ps would show only cropped command by default,but full command with arguments if you used `-f` flag

Comment: @Serg, yeah using it for several platforms makes it bulky! And in the description of `ps` on the man page, there is a line that says subject to change! I thought this was de-facto. I think the older version would've been better... and now `-f` must be obsolete.

Comment: If yo want to exclude header (`COMMAND`), just add symbol `=` (i.e. `ps -o command=`) or use option `--no-header` (the latter may be unsupported).

Comment: Thank you worked!

Answer (score 6):

A more generic way. We determine the column of the command. In this way, it does not matter which switches are used for `ps`.

```
ps ax | awk -v p='COMMAND' 'NR==1 {n=index($0, p); next} {print substr($0, n)}'
```

*Sample output*

```
% ps aux | awk -v p='COMMAND' 'NR==1 {n=index($0, p); next} {print substr($0, n)}'
/sbin/init splash
[kthreadd]
[ksoftirqd/0]
[kworker/0:0H]
[rcu_sched]
[rcu_bh]
[migration/0]
[watchdog/0]
[watchdog/1]
[migration/1]
[ksoftirqd/1]
[kworker/1:0H]
[watchdog/2]
[migration/2]
[ksoftirqd/2]
[kworker/2:0H]
[khelper]
[kdevtmpfs]
[netns]
[perf]
[khungtaskd]
[writeback]
[ksmd]
[khugepaged]
[crypto]
[kintegrityd]
[bioset]
[kblockd]
[ata_sff]
[md]
[devfreq_wq]
[kswapd0]
[fsnotify_mark]
[ecryptfs-kthrea]
[kthrotld]
[acpi_thermal_pm]
[scsi_eh_0]
[scsi_tmf_0]
[scsi_eh_1]
[scsi_tmf_1]
[ipv6_addrconf]
[deferwq]
[charger_manager]
[kpsmoused]
[scsi_eh_2]
[scsi_tmf_2]
[kworker/0:1H]
[jbd2/sda1-8]
[ext4-rsv-conver]
[kauditd]
[kworker/0:2]
/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
[…]
```

---

And what's about `pstree`?

*Sample output*

```
% pstree -alU
systemd splash
  ├─ModemManager
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─NetworkManager --no-daemon
  │   ├─dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-57cfb005-1dc6-410d-aebc-16d8d152abfd-eth0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth0.conf eth0
  │   ├─dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─VBoxClient --clipboard
  │   └─VBoxClient --clipboard
  │       └─{SHCLIP}
  ├─VBoxClient --display
  │   └─VBoxClient --display
  │       └─{VT_MONITOR}
  ├─VBoxClient --seamless
  │   └─VBoxClient --seamless
  │       └─{X11 events}
  ├─VBoxClient --draganddrop
  │   └─VBoxClient --draganddrop
  │       ├─{dndHGCM}
  │       └─{dndX11}
  ├─VBoxService --pidfile /var/run/vboxadd-service.pid
  │   ├─{automount}
  │   ├─{control}
  │   ├─{cpuhotplug}
  │   ├─{memballoon}
  │   ├─{timesync}
  │   ├─{vminfo}
  │   └─{vmstats}
  ├─VBoxService
  │   ├─{automount}
  │   ├─{control}
  │   ├─{cpuhotplug}
  │   ├─{timesync}
  │   ├─{vminfo}
  │   └─{vmstats}
  ├─accounts-daemon
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─agetty --noclear tty1 linux
  ├─apache2 -k start
  │   ├─apache2 -k start
  │   ├─apache2 -k start
  │   ├─apache2 -k start
  │   ├─apache2 -k start
  │   └─apache2 -k start
  ├─at-spi-bus-laun
  │   ├─dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
  │   ├─{dconf worker}
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─at-spi2-registr --use-gnome-session
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─atd -f
  ├─avahi-daemon
  │   └─avahi-daemon
  ├─cgmanager -m name=systemd
  ├─colord
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─console-kit-dae --no-daemon
  │   ├─62*[{console-kit-dae}]
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─cron -f
  ├─cups-browsed
  │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   └─{gmain}
  ├─cupsd -l
  │   └─dbus dbus:// 
  ├─dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
  ├─dnsmasq -u lxc-dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/lxc/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address 10.0.3.1 --dhcp-range 10.0.3.2,10.0.3.254 --dhcp-lease-max=253 --dhcp-no-override --except-interface=lo --interface=lxcbr0 --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.lxcbr0.leases --dhcp-authoritative
  ├─gdm
  │   ├─gdm-session-wor
  │   │   ├─gdm-x-session /usr/bin/gnome-session --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
  │   │   │   ├─Xorg vt7 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/120/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
  │   │   │   │   ├─{llvmpipe-0}
  │   │   │   │   ├─{llvmpipe-1}
  │   │   │   │   └─{llvmpipe-2}
  │   │   │   ├─dbus-daemon --print-address 4 --session
  │   │   │   ├─gnome-session-b --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
  │   │   │   │   ├─gnome-settings-
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{dconf worker}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{gmain}
  │   │   │   │   │   └─{pool}
  │   │   │   │   ├─gnome-shell --mode=gdm
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
  │   │   │   │   │   │   ├─ibus-dconf
  │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├─{dconf worker}
  │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   │   │   │   │   │   └─{gmain}
  │   │   │   │   │   │   ├─ibus-engine-sim
  │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   │   │   │   │   │   └─{gmain}
  │   │   │   │   │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   │   │   │   │   └─{gmain}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{JS GC Helper}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{JS Sour~ Thread}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{Sync}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{dconf worker}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{gmain}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{llvmpipe-0}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{llvmpipe-1}
  │   │   │   │   │   ├─{llvmpipe-2}
  │   │   │   │   │   └─{threaded-ml}
  │   │   │   │   ├─{dconf worker}
  │   │   │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   │   │   └─{gmain}
  │   │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   │   └─{gmain}
  │   │   ├─{gdbus}
  │   │   └─{gmain}

[…]
```

Comment: More generic way added.

Comment: Bravo, A.B. ! You solved what me and @kos were trying to figure out - eliminating username

Comment: Thank you very much outstanding!

Answer (score 1):

I found a bashy way to achieve this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727211/1938395)

`sudo ps aux | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev`

`rev` reverses the output of `ps` and then cut can help you out delimiting the first field(which is the last!) and then reverse it again...

worked for me.

Comment: Processes with a space in their name won't be listed correctly by this method: `ps aux` itself will be listed as `aux`.

Comment: `sudo` isn't necessary for `ps` and  the command crops a lot of the commands, so it's not very accurate, if you would like to work with colums , use `awk` it's much better for that task. In fact, the exact command would be `ps aux | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ( i >= 11 ) printf $i" "}; printf "\n"  }'`

Comment: @kos yeah, I just realised it, thanks for pointing it out, Serg's `awk` should work it.

Comment: @Serg +1, OP had requested `sudo ps` and I thought `awk` would be too complicated for this task and came out with `cut`. Anyways, shouldn't you update your answer with that code so the OP can accept it?

Comment: It's better, but technically usernames on Linux can contain spaces, which could lead that command to mess up as well. `ps` it's just not blindly parsable. I think the only safe method here is `ps -e -o`.

Comment: Yes, I probably should add that code. As for `sudo` , OP apparently also didn't know it's unnecessary. I'll edit my answer in a minute

Comment: @kos username wouldn't matter right?  Oh you mean in the cases where processes are files a user is working on stored in his `/home/username`.  So now my answer is now way useful. Easy is not always the answer :P

Comment: No, I mean that if an username is "foo bar" all the following fields are shifted to the right by 1 field, hence field 11 starts a field before and catches the TIME column as well.

Comment: In that case the user should change it to 12, that would solve the problem right?